# Convert vertex instancing to single mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have created a simple scene. Here are the steps:

1. Make a plane and subdivide it a few times
2. Make a cube
3. Parent cube to the plane
4. In Object Properties tab of the plane, under Instancing, I selected verts.

All this did was make a copy of the cube appear on every vertice of the plane. Now I need to use a boolean operation to cut away at multiple cubes. However, I cannot do this because the instances are not actual copies that can be manipulated. Can I transform all of them into a mesh?

Note that in the final result, I will also displace the plane thus displacing the cubes. A simple grid created using array modifiers will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert instances into objects, go to *Object > Apply > Make Instances Real*.

You can then join them into a single mesh using <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>.

[image]